# KeyError: 'list' with pytube after asking the user for the URL with input()

Tags: python, input, pytube

I try to download a whole playlist in Youtube and use this code.

I also updated pytube, pip, Python, and try to change the code, but I don't know how.

It's my first time to code and I need a good Youtube converter.

```
from pytube.contrib.playlist import Playlist
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube.cli import on_progress

url = input("https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVxmNUcoG69uwwG59UVUyJ9SoLRHE78kp")
playlist = Playlist(url)
print("Total Videos: ", len(playlist.video_urls))

for video_url in playlist.video_urls:
    yt = YouTube(video_url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
    stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    print(yt.title)
    stream.download(filename=yt.title + ".mp4")
```

And this is my error. When I click enter after the link plops up the text after the link shows up.

```
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVxmNUcoG69uwwG59UVUyJ9SoLRHE78kp
-- Click Enter

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonasmaier/Desktop/downi you/codes/playlist.py", line 7, in <module>
    print("Total Videos: ",len(playlist.video_urls))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/helpers.py", line 89, in __len__
    self.generate_all()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/helpers.py", line 105, in generate_all
    next_item = next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/contrib/playlist.py", line 281, in url_generator
    for page in self._paginate():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/contrib/playlist.py", line 118, in _paginate
    json.dumps(extract.initial_data(self.html))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/contrib/playlist.py", line 58, in html
    self._html = request.get(self.playlist_url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/contrib/playlist.py", line 48, in playlist_url
    return f"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={self.playlist_id}"
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/contrib/playlist.py", line 39, in playlist_id
    self._playlist_id = extract.playlist_id(self._input_url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 151, in playlist_id
    return parse_qs(parsed.query)['list'][0]
KeyError: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> url = input("https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVxmNUcoG69uwwG59UVUyJ9SoLRHE78kp")
> ```

If you just press Enter, this does not mean that `url` is now the string `"https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVxmNUcoG69uwwG59UVUyJ9SoLRHE78kp"`.

Rather, the `input()` function displays the URL as a *prompt* to the user and returns what the user enters, so in this case: nothing. So `url` actually is an empty string. Therefore, pytube fails to parse the playlist ID from the (empty) URL.

What you meant was either:

```
url = input("Enter the URL: ")
```

and then when the program runs you have to enter the URL and press Enter.

Or:

```
url = "https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVxmNUcoG69uwwG59UVUyJ9SoLRHE78kp"
```

where the program just uses a fixed URL and does not ask the user.